# How to resolve conflict between routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to have two separate fuctions on my application. One to complete a task and the other to delete but I am getting an error and the form doesn't load: Route [task.delete] not defined. How can I resolve the conflict between the routes? The form only loads when I take the second route out. UPDATE: The delete function now acts the same as the complete function.

```
Route::patch('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@complete', 'as'=>       'task.complete']);

Route::delete('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@delete', 'as'=> 'task.delete']);

Controller:
public function delete(Task $task) { $task->delete();                                                                                session()->flash('status', 'Task Deleted!'); return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id); }
```

Comment: the  delete route change it's request type to `Route::delete` instead of `Route::patch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `laravel` world you should use the `delete` request type if you try to remove 
something from `database`

so it will be

```
Route::delete('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@delete', 'as'=> 'task.delete']);

Route::patch('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@complete', 'as'=> 'task.complete']);
```

you can read more about it in the [Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing) section

Comment: Thank you, but now it won't delete the task

Comment: My controller is public function delete(Task $task)
    {
        // check if the authenticated user can complete the task

        // mark the task as complete and save it

        $task->delete();

        // flash a success message to the session
        session()->flash('status', 'Task Deleted!');

        // redirect to tasks index
        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }

Comment: @ozeol what is the problem now you don't mention what the problem is

Comment: @ozeol if you want to check the `auth` first you could add in your `construct` function `$this->middleware('auth')->only('delete');`

Comment: There is still a conflict. The delete function acts as the same as the complete function

Comment: could you update your question and mention this controller to be more clear ?

Comment: make sure that each form add to it `@method('delete')` for the delete one and `@method('patch')` for the complete one

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks very much

Comment: @ozeol could you accept the answer and vote up? and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a different verb. You can have multiple routes matching the same pattern as long as they use different methods.

```
Route::delete('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@delete', 'as'=> 'task.delete']);
Route::post('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@complete', 'as'=> 'task.complete']);
// or `Route::patch()`, both are valid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
Route::patch('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@delete', 'as'=> 'task.delete']);
```

to

```
Route::delete('/task/{task}',['uses' => 'TaskController@delete', 'as'=> 'task.delete']);
```